# Framebuffer Texture rendered to screen is stretched at certain points

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm currently trying to test out rendering to a framebuffer for various uses, but whenever I have an object(say a square) at a certain y-value, it appears "stretched", and then past a certain y-value or a certain x-value it seems to "thin out" and disappears. I have determined the x and y-values that it disappears at, but the coordinates seem to not have any rhyme or reason.

When I remove the framebuffer binding and render directly to the screen it draws the square perfectly fine, no matter the x or y-value.

Drawing a basic square(using immediate mode to remove possible errors) with a wide x-value looks like this:

[image: Stretched Framebuffer image]

Code here:

```
Window window("Framebuffer Testing", 1600, 900); //1600x900 right now

int fbowidth = 800, fboheight = 600;

mat4 ortho = mat4::orthographic(0, width, 0, height, -1.0f, 1.0f);

//trimmed out some code from shader creation that is bugless and unneccessary to include
Shader shader("basic"); shader.setUniform("pr_matrix", ortho); 

Shader drawFromFBO("fbotest"); shader.setUniform("pr_matrix", ortho); 

GLfloat screenVertices[] = {
    0, 0, 0,            0, height, 0,       
    width, height, 0,   width, 0, 0};

GLushort indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0 };

GLfloat texcoords[] = { //texcoords sent to the drawFromFBO shader
    0, 0,   0, 1,   1, 1,
    1, 1,   1, 0,   0, 0 };

IndexBuffer ibo(indices, 6);
VertexArray vao;
vao.addBuffer(new Buffer(screenVertices, 4 * 3, 3), 0);
vao.addBuffer(new Buffer(texcoords, 2 * 6, 2), 1);

GLuint fbo;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, fbowidth, fboheight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, texture, 0);

if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    std::cout << "false" << std::endl;

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

//the x-values mess up at ~783 thru 800 and the y-values at 0 thru ~313
while(!window.closed()) {
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f); //grey
    window.clear(); //calls glclear for depth and color buffer

    //bind framebuffer and shader
    shader.enable(); //literally just calls glUseProgram(id) with the compiled shader id
    glViewport(0, 0, fbowidth, fboheight);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo); //bind the fbo
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); //set clear color to pink
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //render a red square to the framebuffer texture
    glBegin(GL_QUADS); {
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //set the color to red
        glVertex3f(700, 400, 0);
        glVertex3f(700, 450, 0);
        glVertex3f(750, 450, 0);
        glVertex3f(750, 400, 0);
    } glEnd();

    shader.disable();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0); //set framebuffer to the default

    //render from framebuffer to screen
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    drawFromFBO.enable();

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    drawFromFBO.setUniform1i("texfbo0", 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    vao.bind();
    ibo.bind();
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ibo.getCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);
    ibo.unbind();
    vao.unbind();

    drawFromFBO.disable();

    window.update();
}
```

If you want to see any thing extra, the file is located at my Github: [here](https://github.com/gannonprudhomme/ImperiumStealth/blob/master/EffectsTest/main.cpp)

Comment: Your `texcoords` don't match the vertices. It's obvious before even looking at the values, since you have texture coordinates for 6 vertices, but positions for only 4 vertices.

Comment: Yep, that was it. It's a very simple mistake but I simply never knew that indices applied to texture coordinates alongside positions/vertices, as I am still in the learning process. Thanks a bunch @Reto.